# PHP get 2 url parameters

Tags: php, url-parameters

i'm trying to get 2 url parameters using this code:

```
$page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);
$category = htmlspecialchars($_GET["category"]);
```

and the result i get looks like this:

`leaderboard?category=any%`

and the url looks like this:

```
?page=leaderboard?category=any%
```

How do i get both results now?

Cheers, Chris.

Comment: Did you try use parse_url function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better? And first of all when you pass the parameters through GET you should be doing like this: ?page=leaderboard&category=any

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not for URLs. How are you using the variables you defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (&) instead of this (?) . Example below

```
?page=leaderboard&category=any%
```

Comment: @ChrisCordes - Please accept answer and vote up then :)

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The first query string (URL Parameter) always starts with question mark (?) sign and rest of them with ampersand (&) sign so the URL should be

```
?page=leaderboard&category=any%&anythingelse=value
```